# Removing elements from a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm refactoring some C code and since a while i'm hanging up with a problem related with a linked list data structure. Please have a look at the following simplified snippet:

```
Link apply(Link first, pred_ptr cond)
{
    Link t=first->next,p=first;
    do{
        if(cond(t))
        {
            p->next=t->next;
            free(t);
            t=p;
        }
        p=t;
        t=t->next;
    }while(t!=first);
    //Check the first
    if(cond(first))
    {
        t=first->next;
        free(first);
        first=t;
        p->next=t;
    }
    return first;
}
```

The function *apply* remove all the elements from the linked list for which the function *cond* return a non-zero value. *Link* is something like this:

```
struct node
{
    struct node* next;
    //Stuff
};

typedef struct node* Link
```

Well, the only question i have is about how *apply* remove the very first element of the linked list -*first*-, looks like the extra code out of the loop is required in order to valuate the first element, i was not able to put this check inside the loop without extra *if* statements, perhaps you may know how to remove the extra code from the loop -if possible-, do you?

Thanks,

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element is a special case so it is unsurprising that you will have code for that one that is slightly different from every other case.  So your alternatives are (1) the way it is done in your example, (2) putting the special case code in the main loop with an if comparison executed every iteration, or (3) a less understandable version using pointers to pointers.

The first question you should ask yourself is: Why are you refactoring?  For clarity or because there is a demonstrated need for a faster implementation?  Or ...?

Answer (score 0):

Your code have the logic almost right but have various problems in some places:

- Reading the code, I guess that the `link list` is really a `circular link list`, because if not, some `->next` would be `== NULL` in some node. And the code don't check for `NULL` in any place, lines like `t=t->next;` before the while loop end will execute Undefined Behavior when NULL is reached. Assuming that `cond` function work OK with `NULL` and not enter the `if` statement (if enter, the **UB** would be executed here `p->next=t->next;`). If the `link list` is only a `link list` and not circular, the code need a lot of refactoring.

The first element in either way `linked list` or `circular linked list` could be analyzed separately, in the case of simple `linked list` it's better this way, because the loop analyzing the rest of the nodes is more readable and free of handling specific cases (would be handled out of the loop, and you won't overload the analyze of the other node with checking for the first node), in the case of `circular linked list` the first element could be analyzed in the loop elegantly but can be analyzed out the loop too.

By the way that you are already in the refactoring if this are the variable names used in the actual code would be better improved (p -> previous, t -> test? *i think*, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, the list is circular and everything works fine, my only concern was about the handling of the specific case *cond(first)*, but i suspect that for the sake of readability i may leave the code as it is.